# How to print pdf file without opening PDF viewer print prompt in python

Tags: python, windows, pdf, printing, adobe

I'd like to print a PDF file by Python, without opening any PDF viewer program (ex. adobe).

I have tried some code. It pop up the adobe program before printing.

first code

```
import win32print
import win32api

currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", 'report.pdf', currentprinter,  ".",  0)
```

second code

```
import os

os.startfile("report.pdf", "print")
```

Any code I have to rewrite or any recommend program to use instead of adobe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. download [PDFtoPrinter.exe](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html?fbclid=IwAR1kRJ8oWyduJ_HreuBMdQEIUlUZWYCJFzN8yVGUITmXXd6ei74kVwusSDE) and move it into folder.
2. code it.

   ```
   import subprocess

   def command_print(event = None):
       command = "{} {}".format('PDFtoPrinter.exe','report.pdf')
       subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

   command_print()
   ```