# Python Print PDF file from printer

Tags: python, automation, printing

I would like to automate something with printing but can't wrap my mind around where to begin.

I have some specific requirements that I'm not sure are implementable. The program should be able to choose a Printer by name from the network, take a path to a pdf file and then print that file out through the choosen printer. There are some easy solutions for that that I found online, however, I also need to be able to customize the printer options a little bit more. Which is why I think using the [win32print](https://github.com/tomdy123456/pywindoc/blob/master/md/win32print.md)module is the best for this usecase. If you know something better let me know though!

Here is a little code snippet of what I did with my extremely limited understanding of the module. Note that I am using the Microsoft Print to PDF printer. The reason for that is that I don't want to test with real paper all the time. If that could be an issue let me know!! But I think that it works as a general printer emulator

```
import win32print

file_path = 'C:\\path\\thisisatest.pdf'
printer_name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
file_handle = open(file_path, 'rb')
printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
job_info = win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer_handle,1,("tester",None,"RAW"))
win32print.StartPagePrinter(printer_handle)

win32print.WritePrinter(printer_handle,file_handle.read())

win32print.EndPagePrinter(printer_handle)
win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer_handle)
win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)

file_handle.close()
```

The problem is that the pdf files are empty. 0 Bytes. They get created at job_info and everything below job_info is essentially useless from what I understand. But I don't know why.

StartDocPrinter should "listen" to WritePrinter and WritePrinter should then write the entire PDF into the printer format. EndDocPrinter stops the process. But it doesn't work like that. The documentation is kinda useless too. Doesn't really explain what I'm looking for or maybe I'm just too dumb to understand.

I was able to create a "print" with this Microsoft Print to PDF printer with a combination of win32ui, win32print and PyPDF2 but it's really awkward to use and doesn't take images either. I'm also not sure how to customize printer options there but I'll send in the code snippet anyways

```
import win32ui
import win32print
import PyPDF2

def print_file(file_path):
    printer_name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

    try:
        hdc = win32ui.CreateDC()
        hdc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
        hdc.StartDoc(file_path)
        hdc.StartPage()

        if file_path.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
                pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
                for page in pdf_reader.pages:
                    text = page.extract_text()
                    if text:
                        hdc.TextOut(50, 50, text)

        hdc.EndPage()
        hdc.EndDoc()
        hdc.DeleteDC()

    finally:
        win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "C:\\path\\test.pdf"
    print_file(file_path)
```

If someone know how I could just get an exact copy of the file with images and everything, essentially a copy and paste of the original pdf but through the printer, that would be awesome.

Comment: It seems this is usually done with a call to an external shell command, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249360/python-print-pdf-file-with-win32print for example.

Comment: Some other related questions using shell commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462842/print-pdf-document-with-pythons-win32print-module
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675700/how-to-print-pdf-file-without-opening-pdf-viewer-print-prompt-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435973/print-pdf-file-in-duplex-mode-via-python.

Comment: And one without external commands, similar to your current approach but writing the binary data directly instead of extracting text page by page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981262/python-select-a-specific-printer-to-print-a-pdf-file

Comment: @Marijin can't use the shell command method because I want to expand on the application. The approach similar to mine doesn't work. They put win32ui.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name) before creating a DC. win32ui doesn't have that command so I'm not entirely sure how it worked for them. Maybe they used an older version or I'm missing something. 

But writing the binary data directly is what I need I think. Just not sure how to. EDIT: I  was able to get to the "printing" step but the pdf is still 0 bytes so it didn't work even with the fixed CreateDC / CreatePrinterDC

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "expand on the application". If it is about modifying printer options then I'm sure there are ways to do this using an external call (by providing some additional arguments for the called command).

Comment: About `CreatePrinterDC`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175487/win32ui-insert-an-image-to-createdc is a more recent question that uses this - indeed with a slightly different workflow, first creating a DC object and then calling CreatePrinterDC on that object.

Comment: @Marijn The program is supposed to get some data through RabbitMQ, some GUI and let the user choose which printer they want and some more. I don't really wanna get into shell stuff anyways unless it is 100% necessary but I think that if the application is getting bigger then this approach is better. Would love to hear a solution on the binary problem if you have one! If I know how to convert it properly so the pdfs aren't 0 bytes then I am much closer to solving my problem.

Comment: @Marijn maybe you know this, i just realised that the user from the post also had 

printer.Write(pdf_data) but printer doesn't have a Writer function. At least I don't know how to access it properly. win32print has write but not printer. Maybe you know what could be the correct method?! It's not TextOut since that only outputs text. I need images too